# Symantec Backup Exec Error on backup

Tags: windows, backup, backupexec

Recently we have moved some of servers from real servers- into virtual servers. Since then, we are getting errors like the following:

Error category    : Resource ErrorsError             : e000fed1 - A failure occurred querying the Writer status.
For additional information regarding this error refer to link V-79-57344-65233

This is happening on the virtual servers and also the real servers now.

Looked on google and found some information- like running "vssadmin list writers" however none of these are showing an error.

Comment: What version of BE and what version of Windows?

Comment: ...and are you backing up Exchange and/or SQL, or just file data?  The answer I have (which I *have* fixed this error with before) depends on this.

Comment: Windows Server 2003
Symantec Backup Exec 11d

Backing up various systems, Domain Controller (Win2003), Exchange (2003) and also some file data. Backup of the local data on C:\ seems to be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BE 11d is quite notoriously flaky with VSS, in my experience.  There are a few things you can do here:

- Ensure that the Windows Removable Storage Service is stopped and disabled.
- Run without the BE AOFO.
- Apply the VSS update rollup package from [>here<](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940349) to your servers.
- Configure your VSS and Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider services to Automatic and set Recovery to Restart the Service on failure.
- Run a pre-backup script on each server to `net start` the 2 services mentioned above.
- Update BE 11d to the latest service packs from [>here<](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/downloads.jsp?pid=15047) (reapply the remote agents after this; you may not strictly need to, but just to be certain).

Also, where are you running your `vssadmin list writers` on?  The backup server or the servers being backed up?  If you haven't run it on the servers being backed up yet, do so now, and if any writer gives an error try to identify the service(s) associated with the writer(s) in question (Google will help) and restart them to clear the error.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a problem with Backup Exec and the it's hardware id for the tape drive. Try Deleting the tape drive in BE and Deleting the drive in Windows Server. Then Scan for new hardware with BE closed. Restart the BE Services, and start Backup Exec.

Depending on the version of BE, to delete the drive, you may need to pause the or take drive offline before deleting in BE.

Comment: We do not use tape drives, but "backup-to-Disc Folders" which are on a USB external hard drive (mounted as a local disc on the server). Think it's still worth delete the folder and setting a new one up?

Comment: No delete the folder will not help.